# What is the use for this Condition in the for loop for(int i = 0; i < m and n; i++)?

Tags: c++, for-loop, implicit-conversion, logical-and

I encountered a question in competitive programming and the solution for that include a for loop with a syntax like

```
for(int i = 0; i < m and n; i++){
    //Do Something
}
```

When I changed the condition from `i < m and n` to `i < m` and submitted the solution it was giving TLE whereas in the `i < m and n` condition the Solution was Accepted.

What is the use of `i < m and n` condition if the loop runs only m times? And I don't feel like **m** would exceed **n** (if the answer is it looks for both the variables in an and comparison). What is the impact in time Complexities?

Comment: `i < m and n` does not do what you think it does. This is the same as `(i < m) && (n != 0)`

Comment: `and n` actually means `and n != 0`. It has nothing to do with `i` or `m`.

Comment: You could also think of `i < m and n` as `bool(i < m) and bool(n)`.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without knowing what `i`, `m`, and `n` are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (for example C++ 14 Standard4,section 12 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
> to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
> value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
> to false; any other value is converted to true. For
> direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
> converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.)

So this expression

```
i < m and n
```

is equivalent to

```
i < m and n != 0
```

that is the same as

```
i < m && n != 0
```

or if to make it more clear

```
( i < m ) && ( n != 0 )
```

`and` in the expressipn is an alternative representation of the logical AND operator `&&`.

It seems that within the body of the loop (or before the loop) the variable `n` can be changed and as a result can be equal to `0`. In this case the loop will be interrupted even if `i` is less than `m`.